# Type is not applicable to the argument (generics problems)

Tags: java, generics

Why can't I call the generic methods in my code? The compiler is saying that the type is not applicable. Here is my code in Java. I am new to Java. I apologize if it is an obvious question.  Please help.

```
package adnan1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class myclass{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int length;
        myclass my = new myclass();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER LENGTH OF ARRAY");
        length = input.nextInt();
        int[] data1 = new int[length];
        int[] data2 = new int[length];
        int[] data3 = new int[length];
        System.out.printf("ENTER %d ELEMENTS FOR 1ST ARRAY\n",length);
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            data1[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.printf("ENTER %d ELEMENTS FOR 2ND ARRAY\n",length);
        for(int j=0;j<length;j++) {
            data2[j] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.printf("ENTER %d ELEMENTS FOR 3RD ARRAY\n",length);
        for(int k=0;k<length;k++) {
            data3[k] = input.nextInt();
        }
        my.bubblesort(data1, length);  //ERROR TYPE t[] not applicable for 
                                        //argument int[]. 
        my.selectionsort(data2, length); //ERROR TYPE t[] not applicable for 
                                        //argument int[].
        my.insertionsort(data3, length); //ERROR TYPE t[] not applicable for 
                                        //argument int[].
        input.close();
    }
    public static <t extends Comparable<t>> void bubblesort(t[] data,int length) {
        t temp = null;
        System.out.println("bubble sort");
        for(int i = 0 ; i<length-1 ; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<length-1 ; j++) {
                if(data[j].compareTo(data[j+1])>0) {
                    temp = data[j];
                    data[j] = data[j+1];
                    data[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(t z : data) {
            System.out.println(z);
        }       
    }
    public static<t extends Comparable<t>> void selectionsort(t[] data , int length) {
        int min;
        t temp = null;
        System.out.println("selection sort");
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            min = i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<length;j++) {
                if(data[j].compareTo(data[min]) > 0) {
                    min=j;
                }
            }
            temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[min];
            data[min]  = temp;
        }
        for(t z : data) {
            System.out.println(z);
        }
    }
    public static <t extends Comparable <t>> void insertionsort(t[] data , int length) {
        int hole;
        t value;
        System.out.println("insertion sort");
        for(int i=1;i<length;i++) {
            hole = i-1;
            value = data[i];
            while(hole > -1 && data[hole].compareTo(value) > 0) {
                data[hole+1] = data[hole];
                hole--;
            }
            data[hole+1] = value;
        }
        for(t z : data) {
            System.out.println(z);
        }
    }
}
```

My methods are all right, but I don't know how to call them. In main, I am calling it wrong. Please tell how can I call these methods so that the errors don't prevail?

Comment: `int` isn't actually an object type, since generics can only apply to types of objects, you have a conflict.  Instead of using `int[] data1 = new int[length]` you'll need to use `Integer[] data1 = new Integer[length]` (and the other data arrays) which will get rid of your immediate compiler error - and, please, in future, don't SHOUT at us ;)

Comment: Thank you sir. May god give you all the happiness in the world.